# Import OkHttp to Liferay 7.4

Tags: java, build.gradle, okhttp, liferay-7

I made a Liferay 7.4 Service-Builder module, in which I needed to import `okhttp3`. First, I wrote in `build.gradle`:

```
compileInclude 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0'
```

Then the Gradle build process produced an error:

```
error  : Classes found in the wrong directory: {META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class=module-info}
```

After that I changed the `build.gradle` line to:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0'
```

The build process passed, but in deployment there was an exception:

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogSanitizerException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.toptoken.core.service [1610]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: okhttp3_ [Sanitized]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444) ~[org.eclipse.osgi.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428) ~[org.eclipse.osgi.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1156) [bundleFile:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1189) [bundleFile:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1130) [bundleFile:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._process(DirectoryWatcher.java:1041) [bundleFile:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:247) [bundleFile:?]
```

How can I import the `okhttp3` library without errors?

My Java version is 11.

Adding `Import-Package: okhttp3;version="[4.10,5)"` or `Require-Bundle: okhttp3;version="[4.10,5)"` to `bnd.bnd` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a poi library, it worked for me by adding the line `-fixupmessages: Classes found in the wrong directory: ...;is:=ignore` in the `bnd.bnd` file, leave the compileInclude so the resources are part of your jar file.